# Two ASP.NET websites that shares one database

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

In general I need to know amount of visits on my website and access that data via API to have it everywhere.

For this I am trying to share EF database with 2 projects. One is simple Azure ASP.NET website with one controller which collects statistics of site visits. Second project is Azure mobile service that connects to the same database as website and provides access to that statistic via GET requests.

Locally I am getting such error:

> Cannot attach file '...App_Data\aspnet-TargetrWebsite-20151001100420.mdf' as database 'aspnet-TargetrWebsite-20151001100420' because this database name is already attached with file '...\tagetr_statisticService\App_Data

So the problem that I have 2 web.config files with connection strings that points for 2 different files with the same database name.

How to get this work with one file on localhost and keep it worked on production as well?

Comment: You should be using a real SQL Server instance instead. The embedded databases are really just meant as a means to get up and running quickly

Comment: Have you tried to split your projects, use one project (Library) for your EF and add this one to the other projects as reference?

Comment: The problem that I have 2 web.config files with connection strings that points for 2 different files with the same database name

Comment: Keith, how then the connection string to server should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my target is know visits of page from everywhere. It is not required to use separated service for this. Just adding **new authenticated controller** which binds to Visits table on the same website solves the problem. Service removed then.

Answer (score 0):

This could probably be done via Powershell script which sits on any machine.

Here's a good start where you can get back a list of IP addresses which are stored in an xml. You can then pull the xml into API quite easily I would believe. Also it should be quite easy to convert IP to url or location etc.

https://www.petri.com/powershell-problem-solver - Thanks to Jeff

Remember to watch your permissions!